# Image doesn't cover DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem with an IMG element which doesn't cover the DIV element as it should. As you can see at the bottom, there is a strange padding at the bottom between the image and the DIV surrounding it. I intentionally colored the background red so that's easier to see that padding.

If you check the CSS, it seems that for some reason the IMG doesn't extend it's height to the fullest or that outer DIV gets couple of extra pixels somewhere.

**HTML**

```
<div id="category-list-wrapper" class="sixteen columns">
  <div class="list-item-outer-wrapper">
    <div class="list-item-inner-wrapper">
      <div class="list-item-overlay-outer-wrapper">
        <div class="list-item-overlay-inner-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="list-item-name-wrapper">
          <h1 class="list-item-name">Test</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item-photo-wrapper">
        <img class="list-item-photo" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/900/" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (unnecessary code omitted)**

```
#category-list-wrapper {
  float: left;
}

#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper > .list-item-overlay-outer-wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper > .list-item-overlay-outer-wrapper:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper > .list-item-overlay-outer-wrapper > .list-item-overlay-inner-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}   

#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper > .list-item-overlay-outer-wrapper > .list-item-name-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}   

#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper .list-item-photo-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:red;
}

#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper .list-item-photo-wrapper > .list-item-photo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03aq49ep/) with the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add vertical-align to the image.

```
#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper .list-item-photo-wrapper > .list-item-photo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the property `display` in the last class.

```
#category-list-wrapper > .list-item-outer-wrapper > .list-item-inner-wrapper .list-item-photo-wrapper > .list-item-photo {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```